# Adding dummy rows in a data frame containing NA to increase the row count of a data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dummy-data

Here is the code I am using:

```
for(i in 1:(max_length - nrow(dat2006))){
  datDummy[nrow(datDummy + i), ] <- NA
}
```

Can someone please suggest a better approach

## @akrun: Example

```
    df <- data.frame("var1" = c(1,2,3))
    df
```

## Original Data Frame

```
var1
1    1
2    2
3    3
```

## For loop (Indexing is a problem, I wanted to add 5 more rows)

```
for(i in 1:5){
          df[nrow(df) + i, ] <- NA
          }
```

Output of For

```
df
var1
1     1
2     2
3     3
4    NA
5    NA
6    NA
7    NA
8    NA
9    NA
10   NA
11   NA
12   NA
13   NA
14   NA
15   NA
16   NA
17   NA
18   NA
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: @akrun: df <- data.frame("var1" = c(1,2,3))
df
var1
1    1
2    2
3    3
for(i in 1:5){
  df[nrow(df) + i, ] <- NA
  }
df
var1
1     1
2     2
3     3
4    NA
5    NA
6    NA
7    NA
8    NA
9    NA
10   NA
11   NA
12   NA
13   NA
14   NA
15   NA
16   NA
17   NA
18   NA

Comment: Perhaps `rbind(df, list(var1=rep(NA, 10)))`

Comment: A `dplyr` solution may be `df %>% add_row()`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted using the following code:

```
row2007 <- as.integer(max_length - nrow(dat2007))
for(i in row2007){
  dat2007[(nrow(dat2007) + i), ] <- NA
}
```